# logback TimeBasedRollingPolicy maxHistory

Tags: logging, logback, slf4j

I have the following logback.xml configuration. I am using logback version 1.2.3 and slf4j version 1.7.30

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${log.file.path}/logFile.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- hourly rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>${log.file.path}/logFile_%d{yyyy.MM.dd_HH}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
      <!-- keep only one archive file-->
      <maxHistory>1</maxHistory> 
      <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
    </rollingPolicy>
    ...
</appender>
```

According to the above configuration, I am expecting only two files in the 'log.file.path' directory at any time. The current log file(logFile.log) and one archived file.

When the app is continuously logging, it works as expected and I see only two files in the log directory.

But if the app doesn't log anything for example for two hours in the middle and then starts logging again, new archived file is getting created in addition to the existing archived file. This is causing more than one archived  file to be present.

On the logback documentation,  [http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy) , it says "`maxHistory` property controls the maximum number of archive files to keep". But in my case, it is keeping more than one archive file.

Appreciate any help why this is happening.

Also, the additional archived history files are not getting deleted when the app restarts even though I set 'cleanHistoryOnStart' to true.

Comment: Could you provide logback's internal status messages?

Comment: Any specific message from logback's internal status messages i should provide ? it is a lot of lines to post in the comments.

Comment: I have sent it.

Comment: Which version of logback are you using?

Comment: logback version 1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

I need to look at the code but off the top of my head, arvhive removal is designed to work during continuous function. There may have been attempts at looking further back during start time but  would I need to check.

The issue was fixed in https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-162, i.e. a long time ago.